# XML upload to S3 bucket, ingest with Lambda/Python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

An XML file will be dropped into an AWS S3 bucket and I would like to parse it and move the data into a DynamoDB or RDS table from a Lambda function written in Python.

So far I only have my function grabbing the XML file, parsing through it, and printing out the data.  I am only sure that getting the bucket and file name are working correctly.

The XML file contents look like this:

```
<Locations>
    <Location>
        <d_num>034567</d_num>
        <CID>333</CID>
        <Tool>
            <t_num>JM12345</t_num>
            <qua>1</qua>
        </Tool>
        <Tool>
            <t_num>YT98234</t_num>
            <qua>1</qua>
        </Tool>
    </Location>
</Locations>
```

And my Lambda function is as follows:

```
import boto3
from xml.dom import minidom

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # retrieve bucket name and file_key from the S3 event
    bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    # get the object
    #obj = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key) 
    obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, file_key) #<- and ^: neither seem 
                                           #           to work

    #get data from s3 event object
    file_data = obj['Body'].read() 

    #parse through xml file
    xmldoc = minidom.parse(file_data)
    itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('Location')
    print(len(itemlist))

    for i in itemlist:
      print(itemlist[i].attributes['d_num'].value)
      print(itemlist[i].attributes['CID'].value)
      tList = itemlist[i].getElementsByTagName('Tools')
      for s in tList:
         print(s.attributes['t_num'].value)
         print(s.attributes['qua'].value)
    print("Ran all commands")
```

The end goal is getting the data into a relational database.  So far I just need to know how to parse through and store the xml data.  Then worry about getting that into a database.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What help do you need?

Comment: Well, I guess first I need to get the data that is in the S3 bucket in a form that I can parse through it.  So far my code quits at the line obj = s3.Object(bucket_name, file_key)

Comment: Do you see any error being logged in cloud watch logs?

Comment: You might want to check if the lambda function has permission to access the s3 bucket.

Comment: ok, I thought that could be a problem.  I am fairly new to aws, what permissions should I be looking for?

Answer (score 0):

For getting proper permissions for your Lambda you should:
-go to IAM management console in AWS
-create a role
-create and attach a policy to that role, that allows access to your S3 bucket
-use that role in your Lambda function

The following policy template would allow access to all S3 resources:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

You can create the policy from IAM without writing any JSON yourself